# Element-wise multiplication of different .loc regions of same size in pandas returns NaN's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe

```
data = {'Val1':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
        'Date':['2020-01-10','2020-01-11','2020-01-13','2020-01-14','2020-01-15','2020-01-16']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

here when am trying to multiply

```
df.loc[0:1,'Val1'] * df.loc[2:3,'Val1']
```

gives NaN's

but after adding the reset_index(drop=True) got the result but

```
df.loc[4:5,'Val1'] = df.loc[0:1,'Val1'].reset_index(drop=True) * df.loc[2:3,'Val1'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

is returning NaN's

any idea on why it isnt working and any workaround is appreciated.

Comment: Btw, the term for *".loc regions of a dataframe"* is *"slices"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**DON'T USE `.values`, the proper accessor per pandas documentation is now `.array`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#accessing-the-values-in-a-series-or-index). This was new in 0.24 (Jan 2019) so not many people know about it, they're really trying to deprecate old hacks with `.values`:

> *We haven’t removed or deprecated Series.values or DataFrame.values, but we highly recommend using `.array` or `.to_numpy()` instead.*

`df.loc[0:1,'Val1'], df.loc[2:3,'Val1']` are each `pandas.Series` of slices of length-2.

Assuming what your expression is supposed to mean, by 'multiplying' them you want element-wise multiply to get a length-2 result (not outer-product or array multiply, to get length-4 results).

The 'proper' pandas accessor to use is [`.array`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.array.html) to get the underlying array (you're not supposed to use `.values` accessor, it's generally frowned upon). So: `df.loc[0:1,'Val1'].array` etc.

```
>>> df.loc[0:1,'Val1'].array * df.loc[2:3,'Val1'].array
<PandasArray>
[3, 8]
```

Hence:

```
>>> df.loc[4:5, 'Val1'] = df.loc[0:1,'Val1'].array * df.loc[2:3,'Val1'].array
>>> df
   Val1        Date
0     1  2020-01-10
1     2  2020-01-11
2     3  2020-01-13
3     4  2020-01-14
4     3  2020-01-15
5     8  2020-01-16
```

NOTE: the 'proper' pandas accessor for Series to get a numpy-like array is [`.array`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.array.html). New in version 0.24.0. It returns a pandas 'ExtensionArray' which is a thin wrapper around a numpy array, without copying (so no memory leaks).

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using element-wise multiplication of the arrays rather than element-wise multiplication of the columns. Pandas is trying to multiply values with the same index, so it's basically trying to do:

```
[1, 2, NaN, NaN] x [NaN, NaN, 3, 4] = [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
```

Use `.values` property to access the underlying numpy array of values.

For example, if you do this with your original multiplication, you will find:

```py
>>> df.loc[0:1,'Val1'].values * df.loc[2:3,'Val1'].values

array([3, 8])
```

As long as you have the dimensions roughly correct, you should be able to assign that to your records 4:5 with:

```py
df.loc[4:5, 'Val1'] = (df.loc[0:1,'Val1'].values * df.loc[2:3,'Val1'].values)
```

Pandas/numpy knows how to broadcast the values, so you should find:

```py
>>> print(df)

   Val1        Date
0     1  2020-01-10
1     2  2020-01-11
2     3  2020-01-13
3     4  2020-01-14
4     3  2020-01-15
5     8  2020-01-16
```

Comment: Using `.values` accessor is generally frowned upon. The only issue here is converting the pd.Series into a numpy array; but you can directly use `df.loc[0:1,'Val1'].array`.

Comment: Aditya and Mayosten: **the pandas 0.24 release notes explicitly tell you to NOT use `.values`**: (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#accessing-the-values-in-a-series-or-index): *Use `.array` (NEW)... We haven’t removed or deprecated `Series.values` or `DataFrame.values`, but we highly recommend and using `.array` or `.to_numpy()` instead.* (Also, that sort of note means it's likely to eventually be deprecated in some future version.)

Comment: And the [doc for `.pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.Series.array.html) says *"`.array` differs from `.values` which may require converting the data to a different form."* (which can blow away your series/array's type, lose categoricals or NaTs, mess up datetimes or any custom types you might have defined, etc.).